# Java 8 syntax to iterate over and call a method based on negated predicate for all elements?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Here is what I do in Java 7:

```
public class Sample {

    private List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("helloworld", "foobar", "newyork");

    public void performOperation(String input) {

        boolean found = false;

        for (String each : list) {
            if (input.contains(each)) {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            magicMethod(input);
        }
    }

    public void magicMethod(String input) {
        // do the real magic here
    }
}
```

I was hoping something along this line (which is wrong for obvious reasons)

```
list.forEach(each -> input.contains(each) ? magicMethod(input) : return );
```

Comment: If the input contains "helloworld" and "foobar", do you want magicMethod to be called twice?

Comment: `list.stream().filter(input::contains).forEach(s -> magicMethod(input));` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `anyMatch` or `noneMatch`, whichever is more clear in your particular case:

```
if (list.stream().noneMatch(input::contains)) {
   magicMethod(input);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public void performOperation(String input) {
    list.stream().filter(each -> input.contains(each))
        .forEach(s -> this.magicMethod(input));
}
```

---

Note: the question was edited, so now solution is completely different. The best approach is the one from [Misha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705932/1876620). <del>Here's an equivalent solution:</del>

(**EDIT:** Initially, I had posted the following answer, which is considered an **anti-pattern!**)

```
public void performOperation(String input) {
    if (!this.list.stream().filter(each -> 
            input.contains(each)).findAny().isPresent()) {
        this.magicMethod(input);
    }
}
```

**Please don't do this!!!**

As per @Holger's comment, I wanted to highlight the fact that this is an anti-pattern. Instead of using `stream.filter(…).findAny().isPresent()`, just use `anyMatch(...)`.

And for this specific question, instead of using `!stream.filter(…).findAny().isPresent()`, just use `noneMatch(...)`, which is the approach shown in [Misha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705932/1876620).

Comment: I think, now we have seen `filter(…).findAny().isPresent()` often enough to call it officially an anti-pattern. Use `anyMatch(…)` instead.

Comment: @Holger ok. It was just to present an alternative approach to `noneMatch()`. Didn't know this was considered an anti-pattern, though.

Comment: Well, I think, it’s clear that using three methods instead of one is not an advantage. Further, `anyMatch` clearly expresses that we are not interested in the actual matching value, which might even become performance relevant. But what makes it an anti-pattern, is, how often it appears somewhere, i.e. how often people forget about the existence of `anyMatch`, `allMatch` and `noneMatch`…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for all your feedback, I really appreciate it. I'll edit this answer so that it's crystal-clear this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @brainstorm Please consider marking Misha's answer as the correct one, this should stay as a reference answer.